# __toString magic and type coercion

Tags: php, type-conversion, tostring, magic-methods

I've created a **`Template`** class for managing views and their associated data. It implements `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess`, and permits "sub-templates" for easy usage like so:

```
<p><?php echo $template['foo']; ?></p>
<?php foreach($template->post as $post): ?>
    <p><?php echo $post['bar']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Anyways, rather than using inline core functions, such as `hash()` or `date()`, I figured it would be useful to create a class called **`TemplateData`**, which would act as a wrapper for any data stored in the templates.

This way, I can add a list of common methods for formatting, for example:

```
echo $template['foo']->asCase('upper');
echo $template['bar']->asDate('H:i:s');
//etc..
```

When a value is set via `$template['foo'] = 'bar';` in the controllers, the value of `'bar'` is stored in it's own `TemplateData` object.

I've used the magic `__toString()` so when you echo a `TemplateData` object, it casts to `(string)` and dumps it's value. However, despite the mantra *controllers and views should not modify data*, whenever I do something like this:

```
$template['foo'] = 1;
echo $template['foo'] + 1; //exception
```

It dies on a `Object of class TemplateData could not be converted to int`; Unless I *recast* `$template['foo']` to a string:

```
echo ((string) $template['foo']) + 1; //outputs 2
```

Sort of defeats the purpose having to jump through that hoop. **Are there any workarounds for this sort of behavior that exist, or should I just take this as it is, an incidental prevention of data modification in views?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my implementation slightly, and it seems to work for the time being; I've added the `__invoke()` method to the `TemplateData` class, which returns the `$_data` property, unchanged with no need for typecasting. So in practice:

```
//in controller
$template['foo'] = 'bar';
$template['abc'] = 123;

//in view
echo $template['foo']();                       //bar
echo $template['foo']->asHash('md5');          //37b51d194a7513...
echo $template['abc']();                       //123
echo $template['abc']() + 123;                 //246
echo $template['abc']->asHash('md5');          //202cb962ac5907...

//__invoke also takes $function and $arguments for alternative syntax
echo $template['foo']('asHash', array('md5')); //37b51d194a7513...
```

I suppose since I conquered this mountain, my next step would be somehow permitting chaining:

```
echo $template['foo']->asHash('md5')->asCase('upper');
```

However that seems like a hard one to do. Keeping track of "chain state" is something I tried before with no success. It would be rather easy (but messy) with `__invoke()` in a sense:

```
echo $template['foo'](
    array('asHash', 'asCase'),          //ordered array of method names
    array(array('md5'), array('upper')) //ordered array of method argument arrays
);
```

Can anyone see issues with any of this, or other reasoning for an alternative approach?

Comment: Thinking aloud is welcome. I don't wanna have to accept my own answer. I'm certain someone out there is thinking outside of whatever box it is I'm stuck in.

Answer (score 1):

Echo is attempting to echo the results of `$template['foo'] + 1`.  Since `$template['foo']` is an object of type `TemplateData` and `1` is an `int`, you're receiving an error.  In this case, `((string) $template['foo'])` is not "recasting", its casting for the first time.

Comment: **Thanks thetaiko;** Casting in this scope, recasting in the sense that `__toString()` has already cast `return (string) $this->_data;` Also, casting as `(int)` on echo still throws an error because then I'm attempting to cast an object to integer. I have to use string and let PHP coerce the type when it sees arithmetic afterward. Any ideas on how to avoid these issues entirely? It's unfortunate PHP hasn't yet (or ever will) implement `__toInt()` or `__cast()`...

Comment: Ah, I understand why you're using `(string)` to cast to a string and then add.  However, with the echo, you haven't yet called `__toString()` at the point where you're trying to do addition because `echo` will attempt to output only the result of the expression as a whole.

Comment: You could add a `__toInt()` method to `TemplateData` and then use: `echo $template['foo']->__toInt() + 1;`

Comment: ...Correct (I didn't in fact realize that was the order of operation, I've just been bruteforcing methods) Regardless, I'm thinking perhaps there is something I can do in the `__toString()` method to work this out, don't know what though.

Comment: Or I suppose add a `asInt()` method to keep in line with your prior naming conventions.

Comment: Yea... `__toInt()` or `asInt()` called magically would be great, explicitly invoking it not so much. That's what I'm trying to avoid, as to allow PHP to treat the data type as it would a scalar value, managing it's own type-juggling.

Comment: The other restriction I appear to have here is this; `Method TemplateData::__toString() must return a string value` - Otherwise I would perhaps do `gettype()` or a chain of `is_*()` on instantiation, store the type as a property, and then cast it accordingly on output. Of course, that doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, __toString() won't work for you in this situation.  You could add another method to your `Template` class.  You could overwrite the getOffset method to cast to integer, but I suspect that you don't want this in every case.

Comment: Correct, I want to emulate PHPs own type juggling of *all* scalar values as best as possible, not just integers. Perhaps I'm barking up the impossible tree. I can't rely on extensions either; I've seen many for operator overloading, `__cast()` magic, etc.

Comment: I suppose you could also just do `echo "{$template['foo']}" + 1;`

Comment: Thanks again **thetaiko**, however shortcuts aren't going to ... uh, cut it, I suppose. Your suggestion regarding `offsetGet()` may be on the right track though. With some modifications to the `Template` data tree, if I store types alongside the `TemplateData` objects, I could do on the fly casting in `Template` rather than `TemplateData`

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support [operator loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). If you want to be able to perform addition (or anything else related to operators for that matter), you will need to supply a method for each operator you want to support. More than likely implementing it on the base template class will suffice for common cases, allowing it to be extended later if necessary. While using `(string)` on your object is a shortcut, I would advise against it.

Comment: **Thanks Kevin Peno;** Yea, as I mentioned I've seen extensions for support of operator overloading, as well as supplementary magic methods (`__cast($type)` for example) but of course these are extensions, and I cannot rely on them in production. The `(string)` shortcut I want to avoid entirely. I'm now thinking, in addition to the `TemplateData` objects, if the `Template` class maintained the type (as determined at `TemplateData` object creation) using the suggestion from **thetaiko**, I could implement some type casting features at the `offsetGet()` method of `Template`... Hmm...